# How to use productFlavors for android aab bundles

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-app-bundle

I try to build different Android app bundles via productFlavors. To keep and test the files I need a fixed file name.

For APK's I have the following working code:

```
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name.equals("release")) {
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            outputFileName = "${applicationId}-${versionCode}-${variant.flavorName}.apk"
        }
    }

    if (variant.getBuildType().isMinifyEnabled()) {
        variant.assemble.doLast {
            copy {
                from variant.mappingFile
                into variant.outputs[0].outputFile.parent
                rename { String fileName ->
                    "${applicationId}-${versionCode}-${variant.flavorName}-mapping.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this don't work for bundles. I try to get it working with this code:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.startsWith("bundle")) {
        def renameTaskName = "rename${task.name.capitalize()}Aab"
        def flavor = task.name.substring("bundle".length()).uncapitalize()
        tasks.create(renameTaskName, Copy) {
            println android.defaultConfig.versionName
            def applicationId = android.defaultConfig.applicationId
            def versionCode = android.defaultConfig.versionCode

            def path = "${buildDir}/outputs/bundle/${flavor}/"
            from(path)
            include "app.aab"
            destinationDir file("${buildDir}/outputs/renamedBundle/")
            rename "app.aab", "${applicationId}-${versionCode}-${flavor}.aab"
        }

        task.finalizedBy(renameTaskName)
    }
}
```

But the version code is always the default version code. My build.gradle looks like this:

```
project.ext {
VERSION_CODE_INSTANT = 1150
VERSION_CODE_PLAY = 11500
VERSION_NAME = "1.1.5"
}

android {

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abc.test"
    resValue "string", "app_name", "Test"
    versionName VERSION_NAME
    versionCode VERSION_CODE_PLAY
    project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "app");
}

productFlavors {
    instant {
        dimension 'type'
        versionCode VERSION_CODE_INSTANT
    }
    play {
        dimension 'type'
        versionCode VERSION_CODE_PLAY
    }
}
}
```

I also try to set project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "app"); per flavour but this always generate the name of the play flavour. The Manifests inside the app bundles contains the correct versionCodes. How can I get the correct versionCode from the currently compiling flavour at the copy task?

Comment: Did you find a way in the end?

Comment: No. We define 2 version codes. But we do not use instant apps at the moment. Maybe this works better with the aab instant support?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to replace `def versionCode = android.defaultConfig.versionCode` by `def versionCode = flavor.versionCode`?

I think it meets your need.

Comment: Unfortunately It does not work.