# How to rename and achieve app-release.aab when generate signedbundle on Gradle AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

How to rename and achieve app-release.aab when generate signedbundle on Gradle AndroidStudio

Only achieve build variant release and named it with versionName(which is a combine of buildCount+data/time)

Normally my debug .aab path is

```
app/build/outputs/bundle/debug/app-debug.aab
```

my release .aab path is

```
app/release/app-release.aab
```

I wish to achieve each app-release.aab

at `app/release/achieve/app-release.aab`

Try some several stuff but none work for me... or I am just a stupid

I have a problem with `$buildDir` since my release path is not in `$buildDir`

Do we have something like `$projectDir?`

[How to use productFlavors for android aab bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55282416/how-to-use-productflavors-for-android-aab-bundles)

[How To change Android App Bundles name (app.aab) to reflect App version and build type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593789/how-to-change-android-app-bundles-name-app-aab-to-reflect-app-version-and-buil)

https://gist.github.com/wilik16/ebba3fc09cc78c8d86780db807fcb48c

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle?

[How to change the generated filename for App Bundles with Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508720/how-to-change-the-generated-filename-for-app-bundles-with-gradle)