# How to auto deploy .aab to Android internalTesting?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-console

I just want onclick to
1.generate signed bundle
2.rename it to versionName (which is a combine of buildCount+DateTime)
3.create new release in internal testing
4.upload .aab to internal testing
5.save,review and rollout

Trying to research but still stuck

[How to use productFlavors for android aab bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55282416/how-to-use-productflavors-for-android-aab-bundles)

[How To change Android App Bundles name (app.aab) to reflect App version and build type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593789/how-to-change-android-app-bundles-name-app-aab-to-reflect-app-version-and-buil)

https://gist.github.com/wilik16/ebba3fc09cc78c8d86780db807fcb48c

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle?

How to change the generated filename for App Bundles with Gradle?